# Function is greyed out in pycharm

Tags: jquery, css, pycharm

I'm using pycharm and attempting to include a Jquery function in my html file. however the code its being greyed out (see image below).

Whats really weird is when i paste this code into visual studio code its fine...

[image: Greyed out code]

i've used the following script within the Head, however its still not doing anything

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Is the problem that the code is greyed out or that it isn't working?

Comment: Did you try updating your settings and preferences? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/javascript-specific-guidelines.html#ws_js_choose_language_version

Comment: The code isnt working- none of it is highlighted. When i go to Languages and frameworks it says that i should see "JavaScript" but i dont. All i see when I click the dropdown box is Schemas and DTDs, Kite, Markdown and ReStructured text